# Finding the point on a graph where two lines intersect?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have the following problem: "An ant has traveled from $(4,8)$ to $(4,4)$ in $30~\text{seconds}$. A mouse located at $(-4,2)$ traveling at $10~\text{units/minute}$ wants to intercept the ant. At what point on the line $x = 4$ will the mouse intercept the ant?".

So far I have calculated what the speed of the ant is by using the distance formula
\begin{align*}
D & = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\\
  & = \sqrt{(4-4)^2+(4-8)^2}\\
  & = \sqrt{0+16}\\
  & = \sqrt{16}\\
  & = 4
\end{align*}

Knowing that the distance is $4$ and the time is $30 \text{ seconds}$, i then plugged these numbers in to solve for speed.

\begin{align*}
S & = \frac{D}{T}\\
  & = \frac{4}{30}
\end{align*}
seconds.

(then i converted seconds into minutes)

$$4/30 \text{ seconds} \times 60 \text{ seconds/minute}=8 \text{ units/minute}$$

so the speed of the ant is $8 \text{ units/minute}$.

However, I am unsure of where to go from here and I don't even fully know if i am even on the right track. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: correction: the mouse is located at (-4,2)

Comment: does the first ant continue down past (4,4)?  If not, the second ant won't make it over.  In 30 seconds it can only travel 5 units and it is at least 8 away.

Answer (score 1):

If the first ant can continue down past (4,4)...

Since the first ant is travelling straight down, let's say they meet at point $(4,Y)$

Let t=time in minutes.

The first ant's y position can be defined as $8-8t$.  From there we can create an equation with the distance ant2 travels using $D=RT$ & the **distance formula** for time t.

$$10t=\sqrt{(4--4)^2+(y-2)^2}$$
$$10t=\sqrt{(8)^2+(8-8t-2)^2}$$
$$10t=\sqrt{64+(6-8t)^2}$$
$$t=.801$$

So they will meet at point $(4,8-8\times(0.801))$ or $(4,1.592)$

Comment: You made a transcription error in the final step.  The mouse intercepts the ant at the point $(4, 1.592)$.

Comment: Ah yes.  Fixed.  Thx.